Empty Location Property in onedrive graph API query result
Since a couple of days I noticed, that the query for foto drive items using the microsoft graph and the onedrive API does not return the geo location properties anymore, although it is clear, that the foto in the store has attached geo info.
The is the request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}?$select=location
With or without the select queryparameter, the returned json does not contain appropriate location info. The same code was running until some days ago, like something changed in the default behavior in onedrive.
Any help on this topic is highly appreciated!
The expected result:

The returned DriveItem result contains the appropriate geo location info and is not null.

I already tried

several different fotos
the fotos stored in onedrive contain correct geo location infos

